# How to do Draggable Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

Hi I am the beginner of JQuery, I have used normal bootstrap modal,But My requirement is modal should be drag-gable.I have tried this code but this is not working.I tried putting alert inside script also,Please find where I did wrong, Here is my code.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.modal-content').resizable({
alert("om");
      //alsoResize: ".modal-dialog",
      minHeight: 300,
      minWidth: 300
    });
    $('.modal-dialog').draggable();

    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {

      $(this).find('.modal-body').css({
        'max-height': '100%'
      });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your custom script before ending the body and set `handle` to your class in draggable.

```
$('.modal-dialog').draggable({
        "handle":".modal-header"
      });
```

```html
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $('.modal-dialog').draggable({
     "handle":".modal-header"
      });
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, how to re size(decrease or increase) that madal popup.

Comment: just remove the alert check and it will work, see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7j3gvzdf/)

Answer (score 2):

Use this
        $("#myModal").draggable({
            handle: ".modal-header"
        });

Comment: "Use this" answers are low-value on StackOverflow (and all Stack Exchange sites) because they do a poor job of empowering/educating future researchers.  Whenever you post an answer, always explain how your answer works, why it is a good idea and perhaps add a link to documentation.  Code formatting is available and should be used when posting.